# como hacer redirecciones en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Bien, antes que nada gracias a los usuarios de esta comunidad por ayudarme en repetidas ocasiones con mis dudas en PHP, GRACIAS!
El dia de hoy mi pregunta es algo totalmente nuevo para mi, soy nuevo en laravel y tengo un proyecto creado en PHP puro funcionando, quiero hacer mas segura y facil mi app, por eso decidi aprender un poco de Laravel, el detalle es que no se como redireccionar a un usuario (una vez que inicia sesion) a un formulario siempre y cuando este no haya comprado una membresia, si ya la compro, que lo redireccione a la pagina de incio, por favor si pudiera ayudarme, repito que soy muy nuevo en Laravel. practicamente Basico.

Comment: Puedes utilizar el "middleware" **RedirectIfAuthenticated** para definir que hacer cuando un usuario se ha identificado y hacerlo según las condiciones que usted expone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el controlador incluyes el facade
"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;" y luego para comprobar que el usuario esta logueado y tiene membresia

```
if(Auth::check()){
   $usuario = Auth::user();
   if($usuario->membresia == 0){
     return redirect()->to($url); // SI VAS A UNA URL ESPECIFICA.
     return view('formulario') // O SI QUIERES IR A LA VISTA.
   }else{
     return view('inicio');
   }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, me funciono, muchisimas gracias, fue cuestion de hacer unas modificaciones pero funciono asi: `if (Auth::check())
   if(Auth::user()->etapa == 1)
                        <a href="{{ url('/chat') }}">chat</a>
                    else
                    <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
                        <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
                    endif

endif`

Answer (score 0):

Path Customization
When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the /home URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a redirectTo property on the  LoginController, RegisterController, and ResetPasswordController:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

Next, you should modify the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware's handle method to use your new URI when redirecting the user.

If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a redirectTo method instead of a redirectTo property:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return '/path';
}
```

Recuerda que si aprendes un framework este facilita su documentación , en este caso Laravel cuenta con una muy diciente y fácil de comprender.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication